# Disappearing fancybox calling javascript client side function from asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox, server-side

I'm trying to call one client side function from the code behind in asp.net using below code:

```
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Script", "<script> showFancy('ClaimNewForm.aspx?ordernumber2=' + $('#TxtContractNumber').val(), 'Send to Claim', '55%', '65%');</script>", false);
    }
```

for that, I have added onclick attribute to page render of the page :

```
        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showFancy('ClaimNewForm.aspx?ordernumber2=' + $('#TxtContractNumber').val(), 'Send to Claim', '55%', '65%'); return true;");

    }
```

and below is showfancy function that I'm trying to call:

```
    function showFancy(url, title, width, height) {

        $(".fancyBox").fancybox({
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'overlayColor': '#000000',
            'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
            'position': 'fixed',
            'scrolling': 'yes',
            'modal': false,
            'target': "_parent",

            "onClosed": function () {
                window.location = window.location;
            }

        });
        $('.fancyBox').attr({ href: url, title: title });
        $('.fancyBox').click();
    }
```

the function works fine when I call it from client side but when I'm using above method, the show fancybox page appears but disappears after some moments.

For some reasons and pre-checking, I need to call this function from server side. any help is appreciated and let me know if more details are required.